# Detect data change from different DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**TL;DR**: Detect item change from the actual `<ul>` list and persist the data

Howdy everyone?

I'm currently doing a Trello-like based web-application using PHP as a backend and jQueryUI as a front-end.

The front-end part is made using [`sortable()`](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/), by defining three `UL` elements. One is a container / wrapper with the id `Nav` and the other two are actual boards that hold the items.

**Case scenarios** are simple:

- You can reorder boards
- You can move order of items inside the single board
- You can move item from one board to another

The included code supports all three of them but the data should persist to the back-end powered database (I'm currently on SQLite since the project is in early phase).

### Problem

The method `setSortAction` currently detects all three use case **but** once you move the item from one board to another the order of the list can't be properly detected (since they are in incremented value).

Getting the **bodyContent** like this: `action=updateMenuItemListings&record=2&record=1&record=3`
by moving the second item to the first place in the board is fine, and I can persist that change through the POST request on back-end and then onto the database.

What happens when you move the first item from the second board on the first board? You'd get value of **bodyContent** similar to this:
`action=updateMenuItemListings&record=1&record=2&record=1&record=3`

As you can see the record with value `1` duplicates.

That means I can't detect the item moved is from the second board and I have duplicate items in the order of the board.

How would you go about designing this? Can it be done by the given code or have I totally missed the logic that one should apply in this scenario?

Thank you.

```js
$(function() {

  var debugMode = true;

  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul"
  });

  //Set common sort settings for all lists
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move'
  });

  //Function used to configure update calls for each sort
  function setSortAction(selector, updatePage, updateAction, itemLabel) {
    $(selector).sortable({
      update: function() {
        var itemList = $(this).sortable(
          "serialize", {
            attribute: "id",
            key: itemLabel
          });

        //Create POST request to persist the update
        var bodyContent = "action=" + updateAction + "&" + itemList;
        if (debugMode) {
          alert("DEBUG: bodyContent = \n" + bodyContent);
        }

        //$.post(updatePage, bodyContent, function (postResult)
        //{ alert(postResult); });
      }
    });
  }

  //Set sort update action for top level and second level
  setSortAction(".navLevel1",
    "reorder.php",
    "updateMenuListings",
    "record");

  setSortAction(".navLevel2",
    "reorder.php",
    "updateMenuItemListings",
    "record");
});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );

#sortable_1,
#sortable_2,
#sortable_3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
}

#sortable_1 li,
#sortable_2 li,
#sortable_3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.ui-draggable,
.ui-droppable {
  background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="Nav" class="sortable navLevel1">

  <ul id="sortable_1" class="droptrue navLevel2">

    <li class="ui-state-disabled" style="opacity: 1; pointers-event: none; background: yellow">Classes</li>
    <li id="item_1" class="ui-state-default">Some class</li>
    <li id="item_2" class="ui-state-default">Another one!</li>
    <li id="item_3" class="ui-state-default">Yep, thats enough</li>

  </ul>

  <ul id="sortable_2" class="droptrue navLevel2">

    <li class="ui-state-disabled" style="opacity: 1; pointers-event: none; background: yellow">Presentation</li>
    <li id="item_1" class="ui-state-default">Tom</li>
    <li id="item_2" class="ui-state-default">Jessica</li>
    <li id="item_3" class="ui-state-default">Kevin</li>

  </ul>
</ul>

<br style="clear:both">
```

Comment: Firstly you have non unique id's, the id's in the second table should ideally start from `id="item_4"` and so on.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Implemented the counter and now the id-s increment based on data received. So, what do you advice me regarding the storage design?

Comment: By storage design do you mean backend SQLite functions? if so this is out of my remit, however you can use the size of each table as the defining spilt when constructing the html from the backend.

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike classes HTML ID's should be unique, in this way you can identify which items are from which columns.

Knowing for example that column one has 4 slots and column two has 6 would mean that a request array of 7,3,9,3,2,5,6,1,4,8,10 gets split into 4 and 6 hence

1. Column one: 7, 3, 9, 10,
2. Column two: 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 8

```js
$(function() {

  var debugMode = true;

  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul"
  });

  //Set common sort settings for all lists
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move'
  });

  //Function used to configure update calls for each sort
  function setSortAction(selector, updatePage, updateAction, itemLabel) {
    $(selector).sortable({
      update: function() {
        var itemList = $(this).sortable(
          "serialize", {
            attribute: "id",
            key: itemLabel
          });

        //Create POST request to persist the update
        var bodyContent = "action=" + updateAction + "&" + itemList;
        if (debugMode) {
          $('#report').text("DEBUG: bodyContent = \n" + bodyContent);
        }

        //$.post(updatePage, bodyContent, function (postResult)
        //{ alert(postResult); });
      }
    });
  }

  //Set sort update action for top level and second level
  setSortAction(".navLevel1",
    "reorder.php",
    "updateMenuListings",
    "record");

  setSortAction(".navLevel2",
    "reorder.php",
    "updateMenuItemListings",
    "record");
});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );

#sortable_1,
#sortable_2,
#sortable_3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
}

#sortable_1 li,
#sortable_2 li,
#sortable_3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.ui-draggable,
.ui-droppable {
  background-position: top;
}

#report {
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 bottom: 2em;
 left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="Nav" class="sortable navLevel1">

  <ul id="sortable_1" class="droptrue navLevel2">

    <li class="ui-state-disabled" style="opacity: 1; pointers-event: none; background: yellow">Classes</li>
    <li id="item_1" class="ui-state-default">Some class</li>
    <li id="item_2" class="ui-state-default">Another one!</li>
    <li id="item_3" class="ui-state-default">Yep, thats enough</li>

  </ul>

  <ul id="sortable_2" class="droptrue navLevel2">

    <li class="ui-state-disabled" style="opacity: 1; pointers-event: none; background: yellow">Presentation</li>
    <li id="item_4" class="ui-state-default">Tom</li>
    <li id="item_5" class="ui-state-default">Jessica</li>
    <li id="item_6" class="ui-state-default">Kevin</li>

  </ul>
</ul>

<div id="report"></div>
<br style="clear:both">
```